# clutter in VS Code output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, output, vscode-code-runner

I am using VS Code connected with anaconda. I am using integrated terminal and in every program I run the output is cluttered with the path and the python execution command as seen below. I am using the Code Runner extension and unfortunately I have found no way so far to suppress all this info and just get the output alone. Is there any workaround solution for this?

When I Run Code (`hello.py`) I expect: `"Hello world"`

But I receive:

```
PS C:\Users\KPFRAGKOS\OneDrive\Desktop\PYTHON\Programs and Notes Per Subject\Classes> python "c:\Users\KPFRAGKOS\OneDrive\Desktop\PYTHON\Programs and Notes Per Subject\Classes\hello.py"
Hello World!
```